# How to use npm start to open localhost

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-start

I have just finished making a website with html, css, js and wanted to open it with npm start. Granted, I know if I click the html, the webpage will open. But I would like to use npm. What do I need to install to npm and do I need to change the start to open the site locally? I have very little knowledge with this, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I already have node.js installed

Comment: You need to install NodeJs --> https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I already have that installed

Comment: Do you want to run locally a tiny webserver to serve the `html` if you run `npm start`?

Comment: @MilanTenk yes I was to do just that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To start a local web server that serves the `index.html` do the following steps:

1. Navigate into the folder in the command line, where the `index.html` is located.
2. Run `npm init`, it will ask some questions what configurations do you want to have in your `package.json`. If you are not sure yet, just go for the default values, you will be able to change them later.
3. Run `npm install http-server --save-dev` to have [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) as development dependency, which is able to serve the `index.html` file.
4. In `package.json` add to the `scripts` the `start` npm script for starting of the `http-server`: `"scripts": {"start": "http-server"}`.
5. Run `npm start` from the command line, the server will be started by default on `http://localhost:8080/`

Of course it is worth to put the `html`, `css` and `js` files in a separate folder, to serve them from that folder check the parameters of `http-server`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate into the current folder in the command line, where the `index.html` is located.
2. Run `npm install` to install all the dependencies (if any) for the project.
3. Run `npm init`, for the following next questions, if you are not sure yet, just go for the default values, press enter,  you will be able to change them later if needed.
4. Run `npm install http-server --save-dev` to have http-server as development dependency, which is able to serve the `index.html` file.
5. In `package.json` add to the scripts the start npm script for starting of the http-server: `"scripts": {"start": "http-server"}`.
6. Run `npm run build` to save the build and notice how a `index.pack.js` file is created.
7. Finally `npm start` to start the app on the localhost, (default
   `http://localhost:8080/`).